# Java - Design Pattern for repeating sql tasks

Tags: java, mysql, sql, design-patterns, interface

I have different methods, which queries different data from a database, but the main structure of every method is the same. To reduce the code, I want to shrink that but I don't know how. I have tried interfaces but the return statement cannot called from an inner class. (It should be typesafe!)

Structure:

```
public <special type> getXYdata(some parameters) {
    try (Connection connection = mDataSource.getConnection();
                 Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                 ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(... special query ...)
    ) {
        // Handle ResultsSet and return object of a special type.
    } catch (SQLTimeoutException e) {
        throw new ContentManagerException("Query took to long or connection timed out", e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ContentManagerException("Query or parsing its results failed", e);
    }
}
```

Idea:

```
private interface QHandler<T> {
    String getQuery();
    T handleResultSet(ResultSet set) throws SQLException;
}
```

And then:

```
private void executeQuery(QHandler handler) throws ContentManagerException {
    try (Connection connection = mDataSource.getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(handler.getQuery())
    ) {
        handler.handleResultSet(results);
    } catch (SQLTimeoutException e) {
        throw new ContentManagerException("Query took to long or connection timed out", e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ContentManagerException("Query or parsing its results failed", e);
    }
}
```

But if I call this private method in one of my data mathods, I cannot return an object from the `handleResultSet()` methods, because the return statement will affect this interface method. Is there an option, to tell the `execiteQuery()` method which return type the handler has?

*Attention: It has to be type safe, no casting if possible!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should not use a raw QHandler type, and should be generic:

```
private <T> T executeQuery(QHandler<T> handler) throws ContentManagerException {
    try (Connection connection = mDataSource.getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(handler.getQuery())
    ) {
        return handler.handleResultSet(results);
    } catch (SQLTimeoutException e) {
        throw new ContentManagerException("Query took to long or connection timed out", e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ContentManagerException("Query or parsing its results failed", e);
    }
}
```

Note that you're trying to reinvent Spring's JdbcTemplate. You might consider using it instead of reinventing it.

Comment: I wil test it now. Do you a reference for `public <T> T`? I only know `public T` and I would like to understand it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are open for alternative solutions. If you are using Java 8, you can do somehting like this:

```
Interface MyHandler {
  <T> T handle(Connection c);
}

class MyHelperClass {
  public <T> T withConnection(MyHandler handler) {
    try {
      Connection connection = mDataSource.getConnection();
      return handler.handle(connection);
    } catch (...) {
      ...
    } finally {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Result r = myHelperObject.withConnection(con -> {
  ResultSet results = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query)
  return new Result(..)
});
```

This way you can use lambda expressions so you do not need to implement various new classes for your handler interface.

Comment: Great answer! But with lambda, I can only have an one-method-interface and I need minSdkVersion 1.7 :)

But also a great Idea to use lambda to shrink code. :)